# nsurlsessiond downloads too much data

Tags: terminal, icloud

I did this command in terminal and got this results. Is anything suspicious here that why nsurlsessiond is hugging the bandwidth? (I have turned off iCloud Drive and Stuff)

```
sudo lsof | grep nsurlsessiond


 UserEvent    17            root  txt       REG               1,2      19152 16564038 /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond  cwd       DIR               1,2       1190        2 /
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG               1,2     433584 16602450 /usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG               1,2      32768 37043674 /private/var/db/mds/messages/se_SecurityMessages
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG               1,2    3334144 36961452 /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/0/com.apple.LaunchServices-1030.csstore
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG               1,2     622896 16259470 /usr/lib/dyld
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond  txt       REG               1,2  381434142 16648622 /private/var/db/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    0r      CHR               3,2        0t0      302 /dev/null
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    1u      CHR               3,2        0t0      302 /dev/null
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    2u      CHR               3,2      0t150      302 /dev/null
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    3u   KQUEUE                                       count=2, state=0x2
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    4u     unix 0x954683f445eec9d        0t0          ->0x954683f3d417e95
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    5u    systm                          0t0          
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    7u     IPv4 0x954683f4c140735        0t0      TCP 192.168.107.135:57938->defra3-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    8u     unix 0x954683f3d417e95        0t0          ->0x954683f445eec9d
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond    9u     IPv4 0x954683f4c140735        0t0      TCP 192.168.107.135:57938->defra3-vip-bx-006.aaplimg.com:http (ESTABLISHED)
nsurlsess   166  _nsurlsessiond   10w      REG               1,2  134202708 37151618 /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000s0000068/C/com.apple.SoftwareUpdate/CFNetworkDownload_7ergSw.tmp
UserEvent   207   miladghattavi  txt       REG               1,2      19152 16564038 /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/com.apple.nsurlsessiond.plugin/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
UserEvent   207   miladghattavi   35r      DIR               1,2         68 16654163 /Users/miladghattavi/Library/com.apple.nsurlsessiond
nsurlsess   299   miladghattavi  txt       REG               1,2     433584 16602450 /usr/libexec/nsurlsessiond
```

I entered the command twice; while nsurlsessiond was downloading stuff and the data didn't seem to have change. So I'm guessing this is not the amount of data downloaded by this process, right? Is there anyway to have the information of what it's downloading/downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of posts about this in regards to Yosemite/El Capitan. I personally have a machine w/ OS 10.11.6 and it constantly dl's at 5-10 Mb/sec. I turned off iCloud, tried every reasonable suggestion. I ended up getting little snitch and just denying the culprit, which is the iCloud drive process of nsurlsessiond "isync-edge.icloud-content.com". Even though I have all processes in the OS disabled, this process is being blocked almost every second (I've had my machine on for an hour with thousands of blocked attempts). Granted, this is my old machine I do not use for my primary workflow, so I can afford to do this. If you can update to Sierra, you may not have theses issues, I don't, and I am using the same apple ID on Sierra as I was on the machine that was eating all my bandwidth until manually blocking.

Comment: Yeah, I don't seem to be having the problem since I've installed Sierra. Since this question is kinda old now, I don't remember how I fixed it before.